# How to aggregate based on pattern of elements in list in python

Tags: python

I have the following list of lists where last element is the count for the combinations in that list.

```
[['OY', 'G1', 'A1', 'R3', '', 9L],
 ['OY', 'G1', 'A1', 'R12', '', 30L],
 ['OY', 'G1', 'A2', 'R3', '', 12L],
 ['OY', 'G1', 'A2', 'R12', '', 70L],
 ['OY', 'G1', 'A3', 'R3', '', 14L],
 ['OY', 'G1', 'A3', 'R12', '', 67L],
 ['OY', 'G2', 'A1', 'R3', '', 12L],
 ['OY', 'G2', 'A1', 'R12', '', 27L],
 ['OY', 'G2', 'A2', 'R3', '', 16L],
 ['OY', 'G2', 'A2', 'R12', '', 61L],
 ['OY', 'G2', 'A3', 'R3', '', 21L],
 ['OY', 'G2', 'A3', 'R12', '', 69L],
 ['OY', 'G1', 'A4', 'R3', 'A5', 23L],
 ['OY', 'G1', 'A4', 'R3', 'A6', 7L],
 ['OY', 'G1', 'A4', 'R12', 'A5', 94L],
 ['OY', 'G1', 'A4', 'R12', 'A6', 49L],
 ['OY', 'G2', 'A4', 'R3', 'A5', 29L],
 ['OY', 'G2', 'A4', 'R3', 'A6', 14L],
 ['OY', 'G2', 'A4', 'R12', 'A5', 85L],
 ['OY', 'G2', 'A4', 'R12', 'A6', 52L],
 ['ON', 'G1', 'A1', 'R3', '', 6L],
 ['ON', 'G1', 'A1', 'R12', '', 22L],
 ['ON', 'G1', 'A2', 'R3', '', 10L],
 ['ON', 'G1', 'A2', 'R12', '', 54L],
 ['ON', 'G1', 'A3', 'R3', '', 13L],
 ['ON', 'G1', 'A3', 'R12', '', 56L],
 ['ON', 'G2', 'A1', 'R3', '', 10L],
 ['ON', 'G2', 'A1', 'R12', '', 23L],
 ['ON', 'G2', 'A2', 'R3', '', 14L],
 ['ON', 'G2', 'A2', 'R12', '', 47L],
 ['ON', 'G2', 'A3', 'R3', '', 19L],
 ['ON', 'G2', 'A3', 'R12', '', 55L],
 ['ON', 'G1', 'A4', 'R3', 'A5', 22L],
 ['ON', 'G1', 'A4', 'R3', 'A6', 7L],
 ['ON', 'G1', 'A4', 'R12', 'A5', 78L],
 ['ON', 'G1', 'A4', 'R12', 'A6', 47L],
 ['ON', 'G2', 'A4', 'R3', 'A5', 25L],
 ['ON', 'G2', 'A4', 'R3', 'A6', 12L],
 ['ON', 'G2', 'A4', 'R12', 'A5', 80L],
 ['ON', 'G2', 'A4', 'R12', 'A6', 46L]]
```

Not based on pattern if count (last element if less than 20),it should get combined with its counterpart.

For example,

```
['OY', 'G1', 'A1', 'R3', '', 9L],
 ['OY', 'G1', 'A1', 'R12', '', 30L]
```

should become

```
['OY', 'G1', 'A1', 'R123', '', 39L]
```

Similarly,

```
 ['OY', 'G1', 'A4', 'R3', 'A5', 23L],
 ['OY', 'G1', 'A4', 'R3', 'A6', 7L]
```

will be

```
['OY', 'G1', 'A4', 'R3', 'A56', 30L].
```

Wherever the count > 20,it should be left as-is.

Here either A5 or A6 count < 20 ,it will be merged.Same case for R3 and R12.

Final expected output is :

```
[['OY', 'G1', 'A1', 'R123', '', 39L],
 ['OY', 'G1', 'A2', 'R123', '', 82L],
 ['OY', 'G1', 'A3', 'R123', '', 81L],
 ['OY', 'G2', 'A1', 'R123', '', 49L],
 ['OY', 'G2', 'A2', 'R133', '', 77L],
 ['OY', 'G2', 'A3', 'R3', '', 21L],
 ['OY', 'G2', 'A3', 'R12', '', 69L],
 ['OY', 'G1', 'A4', 'R3', 'A56', 30L],
 ['OY', 'G1', 'A4', 'R12', 'A5', 94L],
 ['OY', 'G1', 'A4', 'R12', 'A6', 49L],
 ['OY', 'G2', 'A4', 'R3', 'A56', 43L],
 ['OY', 'G2', 'A4', 'R12', 'A5', 85L],
 ['OY', 'G2', 'A4', 'R12', 'A6', 52L],
 ['ON', 'G1', 'A1', 'R123', '', 28L],
 ['ON', 'G1', 'A2', 'R123', '', 64L],
 ['ON', 'G1', 'A3', 'R123', '', 69L],
 ['ON', 'G2', 'A1', 'R123', '', 33L],
 ['ON', 'G2', 'A2', 'R123', '', 61L],
 ['ON', 'G2', 'A3', 'R123', '', 74L],
 ['ON', 'G1', 'A4', 'R3', 'A56', 29L],
 ['ON', 'G1', 'A4', 'R12', 'A5', 78L],
 ['ON', 'G1', 'A4', 'R12', 'A6', 47L],
 ['ON', 'G2', 'A4', 'R3', 'A56', 37L],
 ['ON', 'G2', 'A4', 'R12', 'A5', 80L],
 ['ON', 'G2', 'A4', 'R12', 'A6', 46L]]
```

Please guide on how can achieve this efficiently.

Edit1:

Here is what I came up with:

(replacing empty strings with -999)

```
for indx,k in enumerate(process_list):
    if k[3] == 'R3' and k[4] == '-999' and k[5] < 20:
        process_list[indx][3] = 'R123'
        if (indx+1) <= len(process_list):
            process_list[indx+1][3] = 'R123'
    if k[3] == 'R12' and k[4] == '-999' and k[5] < 20:
        process_list[indx][3] = 'R123'
        if (indx-1) >= 0:
            process_list[indx-1][3] = 'R123'
    if k[4] == 'A5' and k[5] < 20:
        process_list[indx][4] = 'A56'
        if (indx+1) <= len(process_list):
            process_list[indx+1][4] = 'A56'
    if k[4] == 'A6' and k[5] < 20:
        process_list[indx][4] = 'A56'
        if (indx-1) >= 0:
            process_list[indx-1][4] = 'A56'

final_df = pd.DataFrame(process_list,columns = ['olflag','gflag','aflag','rflag','apflag','count'])

df_grouped = final_df.groupby(['olflag','gflag','aflag','rflag','apflag']).sum().reset_index()

df_grouped.values.tolist()
```

Comment: Isn't the last element of each list, a string as well?

Comment: its basically the count (an integer to precise).Please note that.You can ignore L at end of it

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place for you to get your work done.  Make an attempt at it then others will gladly help with your code

Comment: Sure Tyler.I have already started and felt that I am making it long.I can post the code here to optimize once I get what i want to.

Comment: I have edited the post with my solution.Help me if that can be optimized.